# Can we save a dying chili pepper plant by grafting?

Tags: diagnosis, chili

I have a dying Jalapeno plant and I want to save the fruits that are already growing, can I use grafting procedure to save it from dying using a well grown Jalapeno plant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grafting will not be able to save the fruits that are already set.  The graft will take time to establish and while this is happening the scion (which is the top part of the graft, i.e. the piece of the dying plant you are trying to save) will be without nutrients until the graft is established.

For annuals like peppers it is probably best to get rid of the plant.  You can use the fruits if they are big enough but the last thing you want is for whatever is causing the plant to die to spread to your other healthy ones.